# PhantomJs `page.set` is not a function?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, html-to-pdf

```
var phantom = require('phantom');   //version:"^4.0.12"
phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
    ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
        //page.set('paperSize', {format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait'});
        page.open("URL").then(function(status) {
            console.log('Status: ' + status);
            page.set('paperSize', {format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait'});
            page.render('abc.pdf').then(function(response, err) {
                ph.exit();
                if (err) return res.status(400).send({ status: false, message: JSON.stringify(err) })
                return res.status(200).send({ status: true, message: response })
            });
        });
    });
});
```

My code is looking like above, I'm trying to divide `pdf` in a different partition. I got an error like follow.

> (node:26328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: page.set is not a function

I tested with following both versions

`phantomJs: 1.9.8`
`phantomJs: 2.1.1`

If any other solution than welcome because currently, only single page PDF generated for long HTML page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own ways after some research and reading deep documentation.

`page.set('paperSize', {format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait'});`

set is deprecated over here. Use `property` instead of `set`.

`page.property('paperSize', {format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait'});`

Thanks